# Run as PIT Mutation Test showing errors

Tags: unit-testing, testing

When I run my tests as PIT Mutation test this is the output I receive on the console. Pit mutation section in eclipse is empty.Is it an installation error?

````
Connected
Received request: PitRequest [options=PitOptions [reportDir=C:\Users\girik\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.pitest.pitclipse.core\html_results, classUnderTest=TriangleTest, classesToMutate=[CurrencyConverter, VowelTest, Vowel, SATM, WebDriver, NextDate, NextDateTest, ExcelSheet, NumberTest, Triangle, Number, TriangleTest], sourceDirs=[C:\Users\girik\workspace\ST Lab\src], packages=[], threads=8, historyLocation=null, excludedClasses=[], excludedMethods=[], avoidCallsTo=[java.util.logging, org.apache.log4j, org.slf4j, org.apache.commons.logging], mutators=[DEFAULTS], timeoutConst=3000, timeoutFactor=1.25], projects=[ST Lab]]
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.pitest.reloc.xstream.core.util.Fields (file:/C:/Users/girik/Desktop/eclipse/plugins/org.pitest.osgi_1.1.9.jar) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.pitest.reloc.xstream.core.util.Fields
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
4:23:11 PM PIT >> FINE : Running report with ReportOptions [targetClasses=[^CurrencyConverter$, ^VowelTest$, ^Vowel$, ^SATM$, ^WebDriver$, ^NextDate$, ^NextDateTest$, ^ExcelSheet$, ^NumberTest$, ^Triangle$, ^Number$, ^TriangleTest$], excludedMethods=[], excludedClasses=[], codePaths=[], reportDir=C:\Users\girik\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.pitest.pitclipse.core\html_results, historyInputLocation=null, historyOutputLocation=null, sourceDirs=[C:\Users\girik\workspace\ST Lab\src], classPathElements=[C:\Users\girik\workspace\ST Lab\bin, C:\Users\girik\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.testng_7.0.0.r201908191551.jar, C:\Users\girik\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\com.beust.jcommander_1.72.0.jar, C:\Users\girik\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.apache-extras.beanshell.bsh_2.0.0.b6.jar, C:\Users\girik\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.yaml.snakeyaml_1.21.0.jar, C:\Users\girik\Desktop\STLab\jxl-2.6.jar, C:\Users\girik\Desktop\STLab\selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar, C:\Users\girik\Desktop\STLab\hamcrest-all-1.3.jar\hamcrest-all-1.3.jar, C:\Users\girik\Desktop\STLab\junit.jar, C:\Users\girik\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.pitest.command-line-osgi_1.1.9.jar, C:\Users\girik\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.pitest.html-report-osgi_1.1.9.jar, C:\Users\girik\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.pitest.osgi_1.1.9.jar, C:\Users\girik\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.pitest.pitrunner_1.1.6.201607050705.jar, C:\Users\girik\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.pitest.guava-shade-osgi_18.0.0.jar], mutators=[DEFAULTS], dependencyAnalysisMaxDistance=-1, mutateStaticInitializers=false, jvmArgs=[], numberOfThreads=8, timeoutFactor=1.25, timeoutConstant=3000, targetTests=[^TriangleTest$], loggingClasses=[java.util.logging, org.apache.log4j, org.slf4j, org.apache.commons.logging], maxMutationsPerClass=0, verbose=true, failWhenNoMutations=false, outputs=[HTML, PITCLIPSE_MUTATIONS], groupConfig=TestGroupConfig [excludedGroups=[], includedGroups=[]], mutationUnitSize=0, shouldCreateTimestampedReports=true, detectInlinedCode=false, exportLineCoverage=false, mutationThreshold=0, coverageThreshold=0, mutationEngine=gregor, javaExecutable=null, includeLaunchClasspath=true]
4:23:11 PM PIT >> FINE : System class path is C:\Users\girik\workspace\ST Lab\bin;C:\Users\girik\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.testng_7.0.0.r201908191551.jar;C:\Users\girik\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\com.beust.jcommander_1.72.0.jar;C:\Users\girik\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.apache-extras.beanshell.bsh_2.0.0.b6.jar;C:\Users\girik\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.yaml.snakeyaml_1.21.0.jar;C:\Users\girik\Desktop\STLab\jxl-2.6.jar;C:\Users\girik\Desktop\STLab\selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar;C:\Users\girik\Desktop\STLab\hamcrest-all-1.3.jar\hamcrest-all-1.3.jar;C:\Users\girik\Desktop\STLab\junit.jar;C:\Users\girik\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.pitest.command-line-osgi_1.1.9.jar;C:\Users\girik\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.pitest.html-report-osgi_1.1.9.jar;C:\Users\girik\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.pitest.osgi_1.1.9.jar;C:\Users\girik\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.pitest.pitrunner_1.1.6.201607050705.jar;C:\Users\girik\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.pitest.guava-shade-osgi_18.0.0.jar
4:23:11 PM PIT >> FINE : Maximum available memory is 4064 mb
Closing server
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.pitest.reloc.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.pitest.reloc.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.pitest.classinfo.ClassInfoVisitor.getClassInfo(ClassInfoVisitor.java:41)
    at org.pitest.classinfo.Repository.nameToClassInfo(Repository.java:70)
    at org.pitest.classinfo.Repository.fetchClass(Repository.java:60)
    at org.pitest.classinfo.NameToClassInfo.apply(NameToClassInfo.java:16)
    at org.pitest.classinfo.NameToClassInfo.apply(NameToClassInfo.java:6)
    at org.pitest.functional.FCollection.flatMapTo(FCollection.java:56)
    at org.pitest.functional.FCollection.flatMap(FCollection.java:66)
    at org.pitest.classpath.CodeSource.getCode(CodeSource.java:46)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.verify.DefaultBuildVerifier.verify(DefaultBuildVerifier.java:32)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.MutationCoverage.verifyBuildSuitableForMutationTesting(MutationCoverage.java:206)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.MutationCoverage.runReport(MutationCoverage.java:108)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.EntryPoint.execute(EntryPoint.java:103)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.EntryPoint.execute(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.runReport(MutationCoverageReport.java:76)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.main(MutationCoverageReport.java:45)
    at org.pitest.pitclipse.pitrunner.PitRunner.runPIT(PitRunner.java:46)
    at org.pitest.pitclipse.pitrunner.PitRunner.main(PitRunner.java:25)
Closed```
````